# how to include images,scripts that are in default folder of views in web2py

Tags: web2py, web2py-modules

I have an image in the default folder of views as an example in the below link
(http://127.0.0.1:8000/cooking_recipes/default/images/nav-logo.png) and even some scripts in the same folder.that is because I am using ready-made template for my website.So how coould I say web2py that those are just images and scripts and not html views?
I found that web2py is treating them as views and giving back a html page with the source code 
view-source:http://127.0.0.1:8000/cooking_recipes/default/images/nav-logo.png

```
<html><body><h1>invalid function (default/images)</h1></body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Static assets should go in the application's /static folder (you might want to put images in /static/images and scripts in /static/js). You would then use the `URL()` helper to generate URLs:

```
URL('static', 'images/nav-logo.png')
```